# How to delete all files in a dir except ones with a certain pattern in their name?

Tags: bash, delete-file

I have a lot of kernel .deb files from my custom kerenls. I would like to write a bash that would delete all the old files except the ones associated with the currently installed kernel version. My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
version='uname -r'
$version
dir=~/Installed-kernels
ls | grep -v '$version*' | xargs rm
```

Unfortunately, this deletes all files in the dir.
How can I get the currently installed kernel version and set said version as a perimeter with? Each .deb I want to keep contains the kernel version (5.18.8) but have other strings in their name (linux-headers-5.18.8_5.18.8_amd64.deb).

Edit: I am only deleting .deb files inside the noted directory. The current list of file names in the tree are

```
 linux-headers-5.18.8-lz-xan1_5.18.8-lz-1_amd64.deb
 linux-libc-dev_5.18.8-lz-1_amd64.deb
 linux-image-5.18.8-lz-xan1_5.18.8-lz-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions, not patterns like the shell uses. What your `'$version*'` matches is the literal `uname -` followed by zero or more `r`s. (`$version` will not capture the output of `uname -r`, it just prints it to stdout.) It is not recommended to use `ls` in scripts this way because the output is not always consistent or predictable. Use @EdMorton's answer.

Comment: @Vercingatorix actually `grep -v '$version*'` matches literal `$` followed by literal `versio` followed by zero or more `n` (and then `-v` negates that)

Comment: @jhnc good point, you are correct; I did not catch the single quote error. If they were double-quotes `$version` would be evaluated as a variable. For the OP: variables are not evaluated when in single quotes, only when they are in double-quotes (or not quoted at all).

Comment: Make sure to escape all the `.`s in any regexp comparison. I deleted my answer as it wasn't doing that and I'm too lazy to fix it plus there's probably a better alternative.

Comment: Please add to your question a short list of some example filenames inside `$dir`. Is it just `.deb` files you wish to delete? Are they custom packages or from a standard repo? Do they follow debian naming conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as a one-liner, though I've preserved your variables:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
version="$(uname -r)"
dir="$HOME/Installed-kernels"

find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*$version*" -print0 |xargs -0 rm
```

To set a variable to the output of a command, you need either `$(…)` or `` `…` ``, ideally wrapped in double-quotes to preserve spacing. A tilde isn't always interpreted correctly when passed through variables, so I expanded that out to `$HOME`.

The `find` command is much safer to parse than the output of `ls`, plus it lets you better filter things. In this case, `-maxdepth 1` will look at just that directory (no recursion), `-type f` seeks only files, and `-not -name "*$version*"` removes paths or filenames that match the kernel version (which is a glob, not a regex—you'd otherwise have to escape the dots). Also note those quotes; we want `find` to see the asterisks, and without the quotes, the shell will expand the glob prematurely. The `-print0` and corresponding `-0` ensure that you preserve spacing by delimiting entries with null characters.

You can remove the prompts regarding read-only files with `rm -f`.

If you also want to delete directories, remove the `-type f` part and add `-r` to the end of that final line.

Comment: This works but it ends with 'rm: cannot remove '/home/thomas/Installed-kernels': Is a directory', no, I only want to delete files

Comment: No problem. I've revised the answer to look at just files. You could also use `-not -type d` in place of `-type f` if you want to remove all non-directories. The last paragraph will help other users who want to adapt this to be more … destructive.